# Android: Handling NFC file transfers via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, android-beam

I am developing an app that uses NFC to initiate a file transfer between two phones. After some research I found that the NFCAdapter function `setBeamPushUris` allows for exactly this and will actually use bluetooth or wifi direct for transfer of large files, just by setting the return value to this function to an array of file URIs.

However, the file transfer seems to be handled by the OS in the background and there doesn't seem to be a way for the app to be notified once the file is downloaded. Is there any way for the app to react after the file is downloaded and perform additional operations? Has anyone had any experience with this? Would it be possible to process an intent somehow in order to react to the transfer of data the same way that NFC messages are handled when sent from phone to phone?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this, but my assumption is that you're not sending messages via NFC after the file is transferred since the two devices aren't going to be held together for the duration of the transfer.  So... what mechanism are you using to do the transfer? My guess is that whatever that is should handle the success/failure callback.